# Jquery $('class', this) selector doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, this

Hello I'm quite new with jquery and I can't get something to work.

I'm trying to transform a div with a .click function:

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#show').click(function(){
    $('.element', this).toggleClass('hidden');
    $(".change-width", this).toggleClass(' col-md-12 ');
    $(".change-width", this).toggleClass('col-md-3');
    $(".blok", this).toggleClass('same-height').toggleClass('h100');
    if($(this).hasClass('SeeMore2')){
        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Terug naar overzicht');
    } else {
        $(this).html('Lees meer <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    }
});
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="blokk change-width col-md-3 ">
 <div class="blok same-height ">

   <i class="fa fa-user-md fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>

   <h3>Hoofdpijn</h3>
   <img class="element hidden" src="../images/behandelingen/headache.jpg">

   <p>text</p>

   <p class="element hidden">text</p>
 </div>
 <button id="show" onclick="fastScroll(document.getElementById('navigationz'))">Lees meer <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

Somehow it works without the ,this selector but without the ,this it will select all divs which i obviously don't want.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `$('.element', this)` is valid syntax.

Alternatively, you're supposed to orient your DOM selectors relative to `$(this)` like a tree traversal. For example, in your situation, `$(this)` references the button with an id of `show` (because it is attached to the click handler).

Therefore, to access `.change-width`, you need to access the parent of `$(this)`. In other words, replace

```
 $(".change-width", this).toggleClass(' col-md-12 ');
```

with

```
 $(this).parent(".change-width").toggleClass(' col-md-12 ');
```

As another example, if you want to access `.blok`, find the relationship between that element and `$(this)`. `.block` is the previous sibling of `this` element. Therefore replace

```
$(".blok", this).toggleClass('same-height').toggleClass('h100');
```

with

```
$(this).prev(".blok").toggleClass('same-height').toggleClass('h100');
```

And finally, you want to access `.element`. I see that you have 2 `.element`s, and that both of them are children of `.blok`. In other words, `.element`s are the children of the previous sibling of `$(this)`. Therefore replace

```
$('.element', this).toggleClass('hidden');
```

with

```
$(this).prev(".blok").children(".element").toggleClass('hidden');
```

Here are some jQuery documentation regarding these functions:
https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: Thank you for replying gmpatzer! Everything worked and i kinda get the hang of it now except for one thing. I still can't figure out is how to get that .element to toggle the class hidden.

Comment: Sure! I left that out to see if you could figure it out given what I wrote, but I understand it is a trickier one. I updated my answer with how to address `.element`.

Comment: Haha thought so. i tried out different combinations of .prev, .find and .siblings but now i get it :D thanks!